# Automatically obtain optimum cutoff point for accuracy, sensitivity and specificity

Tags: regression, logistic, accuracy, sensitivity-specificity

Below is a code snippet to plot the accuracy, sensitivity and specificity. I can manually eyeball and see the cutoff point at approximately around 0.3.  I was wondering if there anyway to print out that value programmatically the point where all three lines cross (see attached image).

```
# Now let's calculate accuracy sensitivity and specificity for various probability cutoffs.
cutoff_df = pd.DataFrame( columns = ['prob','accuracy','sensi','speci'])
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

num = [0.0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9]
for i in num:
    cm1 = metrics.confusion_matrix(y_train_pred_final.Churn, y_train_pred_final[i] )
    total1=sum(sum(cm1))
    accuracy = (cm1[0,0]+cm1[1,1])/total1
    
    speci = cm1[0,0]/(cm1[0,0]+cm1[0,1])
    sensi = cm1[1,1]/(cm1[1,0]+cm1[1,1])
    cutoff_df.loc[i] =[ i ,accuracy,sensi,speci]
print(cutoff_df)

# Let's plot accuracy sensitivity and specificity for various probabilities.
cutoff_df.plot.line(x='prob', y=['accuracy','sensi','speci'])
plt.show()
```

[image: Plot probability of accuracy, sensitivity and specificity]

Comment: just check in `cutoff_df ` where the 3 columns are equal `cutoff_df.apply(lambda x: x.accuracy == x.sensi and x.sensi == x.speci, axis=1)`

Comment: btw, I'm not quite sure that there will always be an intersection between the three, you should check mathematically if this is always true, but I have a feeling that is not like that